# how much time it would take for dask ec2 to setup instances?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I am new to dask.distributed. I am trying to setup a few cluster for distributed job. i am trying dask-ec2 to setup them . When i run the command with required Args ,It stucks at installing worker task. I killed it after 30 minutes.I am using port no: 22 for ssh to cluster.I am trying to start 2 instances .

When will it finish or someother thing is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience dask-ec2 generally takes somewhere between two and ten minutes.

Comment: do i have to specify any inbound and outbound rules for the instance ?